# The textbooks of number theory including p-adic cyclotomic character and Teichmuller lift

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I would like to learn number theory, and it seems like necessity in number thoery that ingredients which is p-adic cyclotomic character and Teichmuller lift. Therefore, I wish to learn these, but in the end I couldn't have found textbooks including these. For example, I had examined Neukrich's algebraic number theory which is one of the most famous book in number theory. It, however, seems that this book do not include these. Is there textbooks of number theory including these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What led you to these two specific concepts? The Teichmuller lift is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb F_p^\times\to \mathbb Q_p^\times$, whose existence can be proved using Hensel's lemma. You'll find it in any textbook that covers $p$-adic numbers/local fields. The $p$-adic cyclotomic character is the first example of a Galois representation. I don't know of any specific texbooks that cover it as a topic. To construct it, you need to know a bit about the structure of the absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ as well as the Galois groups of cyclotomic fields.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For example, I had read Lue pan's "THE FONTAINE-MAZUR CONJECTURE IN THE RESIDUALLY REDUCIBLE CASE"( which is I can't understand at the moment). This paper and so on include these ingredients, and I would like to learn these. Neukrich's algebraic number theory and so on is one of any textbook that covers p-adic numbers/local fields; Nevertheless I had not been found Teichmuller lift. I'll use your comment as a guide and try to find some more.

Comment: Pan's paper is cutting edge research--it's not even published yet--that builds, among other things, on work of Skinner-Wiles, Taylor-Wiles, Emerton, Kisin etc. Its contribution is to remove a technical assumption (residual irreducibility) from previous results of Kisin, Emerton etc. The Teichmuller lift is a tiny tiny tiny part of what you'll need as a prerequesite to understanding it. As an analogy, imagine trying to read Neukrich's book before you've mastered basic addition. I strongly recommend you set yourself a more modest goal!

Comment: I really appreciate your comment of Pan's paper and so on. Yes, I understand that this journey is very very very very long. But, I think even if the journey is long, it is important that there is the road. I feel that it is not bad thing to learn from addition and so on to understand Neukrich's book.